# Doubts with 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

with a raspberry 3 i'm trying to send a hex string to a device connected via serial with a usb adapter. I've made this little code but it doesn't appear to work for some reasons. I've checked the internet but nothing worked, can you please help me out? Thank you.

```
import serial
import struct

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 19200,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
 ) 

 print(ser.isOpen())

 thestring = "7E FF 02 03 04 05 7F"
 data = struct.pack(hex(thestring))

 ser.write(data)
 s = ser.read(1)
 print(s)
 ser.closed()
```

Comment: You need to explain what doesn't work (what you're expecting, what you get) and, ideally, what you have done to try to debug it yourself.

Comment: As i said, i want to send this hex string to the other device connected via serial to my raspberry and get a response from it, the problem is that when i launch it i get "'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: You might benefit from narrowing this down to the smallest example that demonstrates your problem. In this case, that's just the input string definition (`thestring`) and the call to `hex`. You also have a problem with your call to `struct.pack`, since that call always requires a format string as its first argument, but one thing at a time.

Comment: i've tried to make that simpler. I've changed "thestring" variable value to just 10 and passed it as a byte, so "thestring = bytes(10)"  and it launched the code properly, but that doesn't appear to work when i insert that hex string

Comment: Check the docs (eg https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex). What does `hex` do? What kind of input does it expect?

Comment: already tried that out but it doesn't seem to work, nothing works. I'm just a failure i suppose

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here, or at least one of them, is that the hex() function expects an integer as it’s input. And it’s output is the hex equivalent of that integer. Here, you’re trying to take what is already in hex, and convert it to hex. Or at least, that’s what I believe thestring is. I know practically nothing about hex, but a quick look at the docs for hex() clarified it requires an integer.